# Python equivalent for bwmorph('endpoints')

Tags: python, matlab, binary-image, mathematical-morphology

Matlab's `bwmorph(X, 'endpoints')` provides the endpoints of a skeleton for the given binary image `X`.

For example-

```
1  0  0  0           1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  becomes  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  0           0  0  1  0
0  0  0  0           0  0  0  0
```

I am converting my codes to Python and looking for a equivalent function in Python. My specific interest is to get endpoints of line segments in the binary image as shown in the figure.

[image]

Comment: You can translate the octave source code : [`bwmorph`](https://fossies.org/windows/misc/octave-6.1.0-w64.zip/octave-6.1.0-w64/mingw64/share/octave/packages/image-2.12.0/bwmorph.m) and [`applylut`](https://fossies.org/windows/misc/octave-6.1.0-w64.zip/octave-6.1.0-w64/mingw64/share/octave/packages/image-2.12.0/applylut.m)

Comment: Did you look at this [Python implementation of matlabs bwmorph function](https://gist.github.com/bmabey/4dd36d9938b83742a88b6f68ac1901a6)?

Comment: @Ahx, yes I have looked at this, I am figuring out how to use that function. For the time being this has solved my problem- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131466/detecting-start-and-end-point-of-line-in-image-numpy-array